# Open trash in new window on the current virtual desktop on kde kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, kde, trash, dolphin

Clicking the trash icon in my panel used to open a new Dolphin window on the current virtual desktop leaving any existing Dolphin window unaffected in 18.04. Now, in 22.04, it opens a new tab in an existing Dolphin window and moves that window to the current virtual desktop.

Is there a way to get the old behavior back?